# create ipa dynamically on server

Tags: ios, ipa

I wish to create an app with the following requirements:

On the website, the user will upload a pdf. When uploading is done, `ipa` should be generated dynamically on the server and the user should be provided with a `Download ipa` link.

I have seen such sites for generating `apk` dynamically.

Is there a way to create `ipa` dynamically? If yes then how to make it dynamically?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure as I have never tried such a thing but could you not use an xcode plugin for jenkins to build your app and archive it? Where I work we do use an xcode plugin for jenkins but we only go so far to to build and run unit tests not sure if it can do the whole archiving for you.

Comment: Why do u need generate IPA every time? What's your scenario? What's with PDF?

Comment: @orkenstein- User uploads the pdf say an ebook and then separate ipa is generated for each pdf uploaded.

Comment: You can use the Xcode command line tools with a custom build script (xcodebuild: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcodebuild.1.html) or check out Shenzhen: http://nomad-cli.com

Comment: @DavidKaszas - I want to create the ipa(s) on the fly and not through command line. Hope you got my question. :)

Answer (score 0):

The xCode Plugin for Jenkins is not up-to-date. The last version of it was with iOS6 (as far I know).

But using "jenkins" with "shenzhen" (in an "Execute shell") could be a good idea.
Link to Shenzhen https://github.com/nomad/Shenzhen (you can try it out in the terminal without jenkins)